# How to give random motion to particles with geometry nodes within the object

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes

This is the tutorial to morph particles between meshes with geometry nodes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pimbaEE9cjQ

**now I want to move one step ahead: can we give random motion to particles, after morphing to final shape within the boundaries of same shape instead of rest them steady at the end in the form of shape, with the help of geometry nodes ?**

I'm asking here after trying and searching a lots of tutorial out there (I found none related to my above requirement)

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of rest them steady means you want to keep them moving around? I don't know if you have come across this tutorial by Joey Carlino, but it seems to me that this could be what you want or at least be a starting point: [Moving Points with Geometry Nodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVKrucXJbC4)

Comment: what version of Blender are u using?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yes it's almost near. thank you for suggesting me that tutorial.

Comment: @Chris i'm using blender version 3.1 (latest at the time of submitting this answer), and you have given exact solution to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with this node setup:

[image]

you can get this result:

[image]

what it does:

Distribute points distributes the points on the original geometry (cube) and a mixamo character. Then the positions of mixamos character will be transferred to the cubes "channel" and then set via the mix node so you can animate the points between cube and mixamo. The last set position node handles the "wiggling" animation. It starts at frame > 40 (that's when the movement of points from cube to mixamo are done) and the noise texture delivers the random values for the wiggle movement which will be scaled by the vector multiply.

Comment: yes, i exactly needed this thing. thank you very much for spending your time for me.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually it needed 5 mins because I made this already  it is as always in life: if you made it already and you know what you are doing : it’s easy. If you are new and have no idea how it works: you might need months to do it or even give up…‍♂️I gave up 1000 of times in Blender because I didn’t make it work…but fortunately I often got help here 

Comment: it is true indeed. i am noob to the geometry nodes. and as you said me as well can always get help from intelligent people like you in here. thank you again.

Comment: i am noob in lots of areas of Blender too... ;) it's nearly to big to know everything...